# CSS Less watch compiler - how to pass parameter and generate multiple copies of the CSS based on parameters?

Tags: html, css, less, web-development-server

I am using `less-watch-compiler`:

https://github.com/jonycheung/deadsimple-less-watch-compiler

Let's say I have the following `less` file:

```
@headerbackground: #fafafa;

header{
    background: @headerbackground;
}
```

This works fine. However I need to create 2 css files and be able to pass the `@headerbackground` as a parameter for theming purposes.

So I want to create a `lightstyle.css` where the value for `headerbackground` is `#fafafa` and a `darkstyle.css` where the value is `#000000`

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you must Create # LESS File 
First File Is MiXin.Less With This Code

```
.CreateHeader(@Color){
   header{
    background: @Color;
}
}
```

Second File is lightstyle.less with This Code

```
@import "MiXin"; 
.CreateHeader(#FFF);
```

Thired File is darkstyle.Less

```
@import "MiXin"; 
.CreateHeader(#FFF);
```